# Derivative for function at particular value

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to find $\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$ at $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ for:

$$y=(\log_{\cos}\sin(x))(\log_{\sin}\cos(x))^{-1}+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$$

Comment: put $ signs only at the end of the mathematical functions

Comment: @Boris Any idea how to proceed with the question?

Comment: it should be $\log $ not $\ln$ i think

Comment: Hint: $(\log_a b)^{-1}=\log_b a$.

Comment: @Galc127 Then we will get $2log_{cos(x)}sin(x)$

Comment: @Galc127 How to differentiate that?

Comment: @Phys_asr, you will get $(\log_{\cos(x)}\sin(x))^2$ which is different from what you have written.If we write it as $f^2(x)$ then its derivative is $2f(x)\cdot{f'(x)}$. We can write $f(x)=\log_{\cos(x)}\sin(x)=\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(\cos(x))}$. Do you know how to derive this one using quotient rule?

Comment: @Galc127 Yes. Thankyou for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$y=(\log_{\cos(x)}\sin(x))(\log_{\sin(x)}\cos(x))^{-1}+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$$ start writing $$y=A(x)+B(x)$$ using $$A=(\log_{\cos(x)}\sin(x))(\log_{\sin(x)}\cos(x))^{-1}$$ $$B=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$$

For $A$, go to natural logarithms $$\log_{\cos(x)}\sin(x)=\frac{\log (\sin (x))}{\log (\cos (x))}\qquad , \qquad \log_{\sin(x)}\cos(x)=\frac{\log (\cos (x))}{\log (\sin (x))}$$ which make $$A=\frac{\log ^2(\sin (x))}{\log ^2(\cos (x))}$$

For $B$ consider that $$B=\sin^{-1}(u(x))$$ and applying the chain rule $$B'=\frac{u'(x)}{\sqrt{1-u(x)^2}}$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: You are welcome ! Before attacking "monsters", try to simplify. Cheers.